# How to structure an ExtJS Project in Apatana Plugin of Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, extjs, aptana

Folks,

I am new to ExtJS. I am using Aptana plugin for making ExtJS applications, but was somehow unable to run it. I have a project structure like shown below , where in I am trying to run a simple **`HelloWorld`** example.

`helloWorld.js` - JavaScript file,where I am writing ExtJS code.

`index.html` - HTML page used to run the application.

[image]

Is this project directory correct ? Why I am unable to run the application ?

**helloWorld.js :**

```
function buildWindow() {
        var win = new Ext.Window({
            id : 'myWindow',
            title : ' My first Ext JS Window',
            width : 300,
            height : 150,
            layout : 'fit',
            autoLoad : {
                url : 'sayHi.html',
                scripts : true
            }
        });
        win.show();
    }
Ext.onReady(buildWindow);
```

**index.html :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>

        <!-- ** CSS ** -->
        <!-- base library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />

        <!-- overrides to base library -->


        <!-- ** Javascript ** -->
        <!-- ExtJS library: base/adapter -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <!-- ExtJS library: all widgets -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all-debug.js"></script>


        <!-- overrides to library -->

        <!-- extensions -->

        <!-- page specific -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../helloWorld.js">
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your helloWorld.js loaded wrongly.

Replace these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../helloWorld.js">
</script>
```

To This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="helloWorld.js"></script>
```

Your `helloWorld.js` is sitting with your `index.html`, not up one level

(I could not tell if you have loaded the libraries correctly. It's not visible in the folder structure)

Comment: Where should I place it ? What should be the changes in `index.html` file ?

Comment: Ah just replace the line where you load `helloworld.js` :)

Comment: With what line should I replace it ? I mean, where should I keep my helloWorld.js file in the directory ? Which folder ?

Comment: No, as in, since you have your helloWorld.js and index.html placed in the same folder, what you will need to do is just to replace the line above with the one in your index.html. Did you see the difference between the line I wrote and the line you have in index.html?

Comment: Did that .. But no success .. still not running

Comment: Could not tell... I don't have Aptana with me. Why not you use modern browsers like Chrome or Firefox, and inspect the page, check for errors. If scripts cannot be loaded, they will raise errors.